# Limit number of Position in Quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat, back-testing

I have been scratching my head for the last few days trying to understand how to limit the number of position in a strategy. Its a channel breakout strategy (go long/shirt the 20d breakout channel with a 10d high/low stop loss.

I don't want the system to pyramid. Only 1 position is accepted i.e
- if on day 1 I have a signal, and the market keeps trending, it will print new signals but they have to be dismissed as we are already in a position.

I tried everything i've found but i have been unable to achieve anything. I know I have to tweak with osMaxPos and addPosLimit but it seems i'm doing it wrong.

Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
#Import des données
GBPUSD <- getdata("GBPUSD.csv")
GBPUSD <- getdata("GBPUSD.csv")
AUDUSD <- getdata("AUDUSD.csv")
EURUSD <- getdata("EURUSD.csv")
XAUUSD <- getdata("XAUUSD.csv")
EURCHF <- getdata("EURCHF.csv")

### Création des devises
currency(c("USD","EUR","AUD","GBP","XAU","CHF"))
exchange_rate(c("EURUSD","GBPUSD","AUDUSD","XAUUSD","EURCHF"),"USD")
symbols <- c("GBPUSD","AUDUSD","EURUSD")
tradesize <- 1000000



init.date <- "2001-09-04"    #date d'initialisation de l'environement
start.date <- "2001-10-01"       #1ere date du jeu de donnée
end.date <- Sys.Date()       #dernière date du jeu de donnée
initial.capital <- 1000000      #Capital de départ
Breakout <- strategy("Breakout")


portfolio.st <- account.st <- strat.st <- "Breakout"

if (!exists('.blotter')) .blotter <- new.env()
if (!exists('.strategy')) .strategy <- new.env()

initPortf(portfolio.st,        #nom du book
          symbols = symbols,  #list des instruments
          initDate=init.date,  #date de départ du book
          currency='USD')     #devise de référence du book

initAcct(account.st,                 #nom du compte
         portfolios = portfolio.st,  #nom du portfeuille rattaché au compte
         initDate = init.date,       #date de départ du compte
         currency = "USD",           #devise du compte
         initEq = initial.capital)   #capital de départ du compte

initOrders(portfolio.st,            #initialisation du container des orgers
           initDate = init.date)    #date de départ du book d'ordre

strategy("Breakout",store = TRUE)


#Definition des indicateurs
add.indicator("Breakout",
              name = "DonchianChannel",
              arguments=list(HL=quote(cbind(Hi(mktdata)[,1],Lo(mktdata)[,1])), n=20,include.lag=TRUE), label="Donchian20")

add.indicator("Breakout",
              name = "DonchianChannel",
              arguments=list(HL=quote(cbind(Hi(mktdata)[,1],Lo(mktdata)[,1])), n=10,include.lag=TRUE), label="Donchian10")


##Definition des signaux

add.signal("Breakout",                #nom de la strategie
           name="sigCrossover",      #type de signal
           arguments = list(columns =c("Close","high.Donchian20"), #liste des colonnes pour déterminer le signal
                            relationship="gt"),   #type de relation du signal (sup ou égal, sup, inférieur etc..)
           label = "long")        #label de la colonne du signal

add.signal("Breakout",                #nom de la strategie
           name="sigCrossover",      #type de signal
           arguments = list(columns =c("Close","low.Donchian10"), #liste des colonnes pour déterminer le signal
                            relationship="lt"),   #type de relation du signal (sup ou égal, sup, inférieur etc..)
           label = "exitlong")        #label de la colonne du signal


add.signal("Breakout",                #nom de la strategie
           name="sigCrossover",      #type de signal
           arguments = list(columns =c("Close","low.Donchian20"), #liste des colonnes pour déterminer le signal
                            relationship="lt"),   #type de relation du signal (sup ou égal, sup, inférieur etc..)
           label = "short")   

add.signal("Breakout",                #nom de la strategie
           name="sigCrossover",      #type de signal
           arguments = list(columns =c("Close","high.Donchian10"), #liste des colonnes pour déterminer le signal
                            relationship="gt"),   #type de relation du signal (sup ou égal, sup, inférieur etc..)
           label = "exitshort")        #label de la colonne du signal


#Limite

#addPosLimit( portfolio = "Breakout", # add position limit rules
#             symbol = "AUDUSD",
#            timestamp = init.date,
#            maxpos = tradesize)

addPosLimit("Breakout","AUDUSD",maxpos = 1, minpos = -1,timestamp =  as.POSIXct(init.date))
getPosLimit(portfolio = "Breakout","AUDUSD", timestamp = as.POSIXct(init.date))

##Definition des règles

add.rule("Breakout",                               #nom de la strategie 
         name = "ruleSignal",                      #
         arguments = list(sigcol ="long",          #nom de la colonne à vérifier
                          sigval = TRUE,           #Application de la règle si signal
                          orderqty=tradesize,        #taille de l'ordre
                          osFun = osMaxPos,
                          replace = FALSE,
                          ordertype = "market",    #type d'ordre
                          orderside ="long"),   #sens
         type = "enter",          #ouverture ou fermeture de pose
         label = "Enterlong")    #label si exécution

add.rule("Breakout",                                  #nom de la strategie 
         name = "ruleSignal",                      #
         arguments = list(sigcol ="exitlong",          #nom de la colonne à vérifier
                          sigval = TRUE,           #Application de la règle si signal
                          orderqty="all",        #taille de l'ordre
                          replace = FALSE,
                          ordertype = "market",    #type d'ordre
                          orderside ="long"),   #sens
         type = "exit",          #ouverture ou fermeture de pose
         label = "Exitlong")    #label si exécution


add.rule("Breakout",                                  #nom de la strategie 
         name = "ruleSignal",                      #
         arguments = list(sigcol ="short",          #nom de la colonne à vérifier
                          sigval = TRUE,           #Application de la règle si signal
                          orderqty=-tradesize,#taille de l'ordre
                          replace = FALSE,
                          ordertype = "market",    #type d'ordre
                          orderside ="short"),   #sens
         type = "enter",          #ouverture ou fermeture de pose
         label = "Entershort")    #label si exécution

add.rule("Breakout",                                  #nom de la strategie 
         name = "ruleSignal",                      #
         arguments = list(sigcol ="exitshort",          #nom de la colonne à vérifier
                          sigval = TRUE,           #Application de la règle si signal
                          orderqty="all",#taille de l'ordre
                          osFun = osMaxPos,
                          replace = FALSE,
                          ordertype = "market",    #type d'ordre
                          orderside ="short"),   #sens
         type = "exit",          #ouverture ou fermeture de pose
         label = "Exitshort")    #label si exécution






out <- applyStrategy("Breakout", portfolios = portfolio.st)
```

Comment: You need to specify what package contains the `getdata` function.  You also need to provide some data (we cannot access the CSV files on your computer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few problems with your code. I'll try to explain all of them.

#### Initialization

You usually do not need to set `initDate` in your calls to `initPortf`, `initAcct`, and `initOrders`. Setting that value incorrectly can cause issues. So those calls should be:

```
initPortf(portfolio.st,       #nom du book
          symbols = symbols,  #list des instruments
          currency='USD')     #devise de référence du book

initAcct(account.st,                 #nom du compte
         portfolios = portfolio.st,  #nom du portfeuille rattaché au compte
         currency = "USD",           #devise du compte
         initEq = initial.capital)   #capital de départ du compte

initOrders(portfolio.st)             #initialisation du container des orgers
```

#### Position limits

You set max/min trade size to 1 in your call to `addPosLimit`, but your trade size is 1 million. So any order will be rejected because it would put you over your position limit. You should also know that the `timestamp` argument to `addPosLimit` determines when the limits go into effect. If you always want them in effect, you should set the timestamp to a time before the first observation in your data. Also note that you only created position limits for `AUDUSD`. You need to create position limits for each symbol.

```
addPosLimit("Breakout", "GBPUSD", maxpos = tradesize, timestamp = start(GBPUSD)-1)
addPosLimit("Breakout", "AUDUSD", maxpos = tradesize, timestamp = start(AUDUSD)-1)
addPosLimit("Breakout", "EURUSD", maxpos = tradesize, timestamp = start(EURUSD)-1)
```

#### Rules

One problem is that you passed `osFun` to `ruleSignal`. `ruleSignal` does not have an `osFun` argument. The argument is `osFUN` (case matters).  The other problem is that you specified `osFun = osMaxPos` on your short *exit* rule, not the *entry* rule.

```
add.rule("Breakout", name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "long",      #nom de la colonne à vérifier
                          sigval = TRUE,        #Application de la règle si signal
                          orderqty = tradesize, #taille de l'ordre
                          osFUN = osMaxPos,
                          replace = FALSE,
                          ordertype = "market", #type d'ordre
                          orderside = "long"),  #sens
         type = "enter", label = "Enterlong")

add.rule("Breakout", name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "exitlong",  #nom de la colonne à vérifier
                          sigval = TRUE,        #Application de la règle si signal
                          orderqty = "all",     #taille de l'ordre
                          replace = FALSE,
                          ordertype = "market", #type d'ordre
                          orderside = "long"),  #sens
         type = "exit", label = "Exitlong")

add.rule("Breakout", name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "short",     #nom de la colonne à vérifier
                          sigval = TRUE,        #Application de la règle si signal
                          orderqty = -tradesize,#taille de l'ordre
                          osFUN = osMaxPos,
                          replace = FALSE,
                          ordertype = "market",  #type d'ordre
                          orderside = "short"),  #sens
         type = "enter", label = "Entershort")

add.rule("Breakout", name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "exitshort",  #nom de la colonne à vérifier
                          sigval = TRUE,         #Application de la règle si signal
                          orderqty = "all",      #taille de l'ordre
                          replace = FALSE,
                          ordertype = "market",  #type d'ordre
                          orderside = "short"),  #sens
         type = "exit", label = "Exitshort")
```

Comment: You are fantastic. Thanks for taking the time to analyse my bad code.

Comment: @NicolasB You should consider accepting this very thorough answer

Comment: what do you mean @FXQuantTrader ?

Comment: @NicolasB: see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I accepted the answer. Once again, I greatly appreciate your help Joshua :)

Comment: I've been trying this with a futures strategy where my max position is 1/-1. This means that if I trade a reversal, I would expect an order size of 2 (to go from position -1 to position 1 or vice versa). Yet in my order book, no order exceeds size 1. Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?